# Google map clear old markers when new markers are plotted

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm calling an API and plotting new markers after few seconds interval. The new markers get plotted but the old one still remains. I want to clear the old marker when the new markers are plotted. Here is my code.

```
var myMarkers = [];  
var i;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(12.967086,77.746564),
    map: map,
});       
setInterval(function(){
        $.post(contextPath+"/api/getlocations", {} , function(data){
            var response = data;
            var locations = response.locations;
            var marker, i;

            for (var i = myMarkers.length; i > 0; i--) {
                myMarkers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            myMarkers = [];
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
                myMarkers.push(marker);
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
```

*map is initialized.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve - sounds like a "moving marker". If so, move your "var marker"  outside the function, Then remove first for(...) and let just marker.setMap(null) and it should work as a "moving marker".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a myMarkers at window level for manage the markers collection

```
var myMarkers = [];
```

before create the markers clear the previous

```
for (i = 0;  i <  myMarkers.length;  i++) {

  myMarkers.[i].setMap(null);
}
myMarkers = [];
```

..

```
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });
```

// add the marker at you markes collection

```
  myMarkers.push(marker);
```

Comment: Now getting error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined

Comment: I have update  the code adding the clear of myMarkers after the loop for setMap(null) ..try  .. and let me know

Comment: same error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined

Comment: are you sure that all markers  you create are push in myMarkers?  and you are referring to myMarkers[i].setMap(null);?

Comment: I have updated the code with your changes. plz check. still the error

Comment: i have update the answer using the for in reverse mode  .. try this way

Comment: I have fixed it. Have initialized the marker outside the API call and with your suggestion it fixed. I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks